# Get the pdf doc url indexed

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, pdf, public-html

I have a URL to a PDF document which I uploaded to the public_html/docs folder. How do I get search engines to index this link and PDF document?

When I submit the URL to the search console it does not index it, instead provides a message saying there was a problem.

Related info.:
I have Cloudflare, do I need to make changes to it?
Do I add something to robots.txt or sitemap?

I also noticed that the URL does not redirect to one format example: https://www[.]website[.]com/docs/my-upload-file.pdf and without www i.e. https://website[.]com/docs/my-upload-file.pdf open individually and as for my main domain no matter how you enter the URL it will always go to the https://www. version. So, could this be a sign of the issue?

@StephenOstermiller I have a link as mentioned in the question, what does indexability have to do with the quality of the content? Quality of the content affects the rankings and not the indexability factor. You can have an image of a penguin on your website and get the URL crawled and indexed by Google. Lastly, you say this question has been answered, can you tell me where? I have ripped all related questions and all of them point to deindex the pdf and not get it indexed so this question is unique

Comment: You need to link to content from your site to get search engines to index it.  Submitting it or putting it in a sitemap is often not enough.   The content also has to be unique and the search engines have to think it is high quality.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have a link as mentioned in the question, what does indexability have to do with the quality of the content? Quality of the content affects the rankings and not the indexability factor. You can have an image of a penguin on your website and get the URL crawled and indexed by Google. Lastly, you say this question has been answered, can you tell me where? I have ripped all related questions and all of them point to deindex the pdf and not get it indexed so this question is unique.

Comment: Does Google Search Console elaborate on what kind of problem it saw?

Comment: Quality is absolutely a "is this content even worth indexing" factor for Google.  Google evaluates image quality differently than text quality, but images don't get indexed if they are low quality.   For images Google views quality as large size, full color photographs.   Also keep in mind that crawling is not the same as indexing.  Google may crawl a piece of content many times and still decide not to include it in the search index.

Comment: Just one link may not be enough, especially not from a page buried deep in your site.  If you really want the PDF indexed, try creating several links to it, link it from prominent place, and try to get external links too.   That and make sure it is unique content that would answer the question of somebody searching for it.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister No, it just says that there was problem and try again later however the normal urls i.e. mywebsite[.]com/normail-urls/ to get indexed but just the doc file url i.e. mywebsite[.]com/docs/thefile.pdf has this issue.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Link building has nothing to do with getting a site indexed. I am an SEO guy by profession for the past 6 years so trust me when I say you are wrong. Let me explain, when you create a page on your website you can submit it to Google search console for it to be indexed. This means that Google knows that this URL exists on your website now it can be on the 100th position of search results. It does not matter how good the content or how many inks it has as all these are ranking factors. The problem here for me is Google is not crawling my public_html/docs/ folder files.

Comment: @Egochi I'm sorry to say but Stephen is right, page quality helps determine whether a page gets indexed. "Google doesn't crawl all the pages on the web, and we don't index all the pages we crawl. It's perfectly normal for not all the pages on a site to be indexed." https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34441?hl=en

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister No, you are wrong. I am out, deleting my account. Thanks .